# Im having an issue displaying a image from a URL in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

As far as I can see my code is exactly like the code on W3schools except im making a new image instead of using one already in the html, but i cant get it to display anything

```
<body>
<center><canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="750"></canvas></center>
<script>
    function newImage(src, width, height) {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = src;
            img.width = width;
            img.height = height;
            return img;
        }   

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var i = newImage("http://i.imgur.com/ELsS4mN.jpg", 1000, 750);
    ctx.drawImage(i,0,0);
</script>
```

Comment: Looks good http://jsfiddle.net/xo09spsu/

Comment: weird thanks any idea why it shows a blank page when i run it from a local html file with chrome?

Comment: because your browser is blocking it.. probably with a allow-same-origin security flagging on the request

Comment: Use your Web Inspecter (F12 usually), go to your console log and invoke the newImage method (using the intermediate window in the console) to verify that is the reason..

You can likely turn off these browser security measures by closing down your browser and opening the application with a particular argument (command)... ensure that all browser instances (including hidden windows are closed in your task manager)

Comment: No, it's not security. It's timing issue, because by the time of rendering on canvas image is not yet available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears because you return image object before it is fully downloaded. Because of that canvas fails to render image data as background image.

You should make use of `onload` callback function and `drawImage` only when image data is completely available. This should work:

```
function newImage(src, width, height, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.onload = function () {
        callback(img);
    };
    img.src = src;
}

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");

newImage("http://i.imgur.com/ELsS4mN.jpg", 1000, 750, function(image) {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
});
```

Note how instead of returning image from `newImage` function, you pass callback function in it and invoke it once download complete.

```js
    function newImage(src, width, height, callback) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        img.onload = function () {
            callback(img);
        };
        img.src = src;
    }
    
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    newImage("http://i.imgur.com/ELsS4mN.jpg", 1000, 750, function(image) {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    });
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="750"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok this totally makes sense, your code fixes the problem. I was wondering if it was because its a fairly large picture. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, it's because the image was pretty big.

Comment: Also if it solves you issue, consider accepting the answer to close the question.